# Dataprep Job Failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataprep

In dataprep jobs I have a transform Failed with the only information being:

Job Failed : `java.lang.NullPointerException: jobId`.

It does not even go to dataflow jobs, I have no logs or anything to go with.
Any ideas why, or how to have more info to correct this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After contacting Google-Trifacta support, there is a workaround:

- disabling the Profile Results option in the run page